# Select space between marks in R plot

Tags: r, graph, plot, axis

I have the following table

> agrup1

```
     loaddate     recup recup_gente
1  2014-04-16 0.4213183   0.7294452
2  2014-05-16 0.4539847   0.7587836
3  2014-06-16 0.4506581   0.7597915
4  2014-07-16 0.4500220   0.7682811
5  2014-08-16 0.4402933   0.4488161
6  2014-09-01 0.5365479   0.6765825
7  2014-10-01 0.5069230   0.6782983
8  2014-11-01 0.7598421   0.8134287
9  2014-12-03 0.7477045   0.8073076
10 2015-01-05 0.5060155   0.5814931
```

I need to do a graph with 2 axis. My code is:

```
par(mar=c(4,5,4,4))
plot(agrup1$loaddate[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'], 
     agrup1$recup[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'], yaxt='n', ylab='', 
     type='o', xlab='fecha de carga',
     main='Recupero alcanzado por mes', cex.main=.9,
     ylim=c((min(agrup1$recup)-0.1),(max(agrup1$recup)+0.1)))
par(new = T)
plot(agrup1$loaddate[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'], 
     agrup1$recup_gente[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'],
      yaxt='n', ylab='', xlab='', type='o', col='red',
     , cex.main=.9 ,
     ylim=c((min(agrup1$recup_gente)-0.1),(max(agrup1$recup_gente)+0.1)))
axis(2, at=pretty(agrup1$recup[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01']), 
     lab=paste(round(pretty(agrup1$recup[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'])*100,2), '%'),
     las=1)
axis(4, at=pretty(agrup1$recup_gente[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01']), 
     lab=paste(round(pretty(agrup1$recup_gente[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'])*100,2), '%'), 
     las=1, col='red', col.axis='red')
mtext(side = 2, line = 2.8, "recupero $")
mtext(side = 4, line = 2.8, "recupero clientes", col='red')
```

And I get the following graph:

[image]

I'd like to have the same space in both axis... Axis one marks should be by 10%, not counting each time 5% more. How can I do this?

Comment: I guess, you should set the same parameter "at" for both axes.

Comment: If the axes are identical, why do you need 2 axes?  That's just visually confusing and chart junk.  How about simply plotting the two series in different colours?

Comment: Hi, In this case they are identical, but they might not be. Look at ylim in both plots: they refer to different series.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend 1 axis for this plot.

```
agrup1 = structure(list(loaddate = structure(c(16176, 16206, 16237, 16267, 
16298, 16314, 16344, 16375, 16407, 16440), class = "Date"), recup = c(0.4213183, 
0.4539847, 0.4506581, 0.450022, 0.4402933, 0.5365479, 0.506923, 
0.7598421, 0.7477045, 0.5060155), recup_gente = c(0.7294452, 
0.7587836, 0.7597915, 0.7682811, 0.4488161, 0.6765825, 0.6782983, 
0.8134287, 0.8073076, 0.5814931)), .Names = c("loaddate", "recup", 
"recup_gente"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

par(mar=c(4,5,4,4))
plot(agrup1$loaddate[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'], 
     agrup1$recup[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'], yaxt='n', ylab='', 
     type='o', xlab='fecha de carga',
     main='Recupero alcanzado por mes', cex.main=.9,
     ylim=c((min(agrup1$recup)-0.1),(max(agrup1$recup)+0.1)))
lines(agrup1$loaddate[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'], 
      agrup1$recup_gente[agrup1$loaddate<'2015-01-01'],
      type='o', col='red', cex.main=.9)
axis(2, at=pretty(seq(0.4,0.8,0.1)), 
     lab=paste0(seq(40,80,10), '%'),
     las=1)
axis(4, at=pretty(seq(0.4,0.8,0.1)), 
     lab=paste0(seq(40,80,10), '%'), 
     las=1, col='red', col.axis='red')
mtext(side = 2, line = 2.8, "recupero $")
mtext(side = 4, line = 2.8, "recupero clientes", col='red')
```

[image]